# C# Get schema information when validating xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, validation, schema

I'm trying to validate some XML against a schema and gather as much information as possible to provide valuable error messages to the user.

I've managed to validate a serialized object against an XSD. My ValidationEventHandler is being called properly for all errors and I get get some information there. The only problem is that schema information is not available at this point - I'm trying to get to the schema type of the element. i.e. given the following schema element, I would like to get "BookType"

```
<element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TypeOfBook" type="myTypes:BookType" />
```

I believe schema/validation information is being inserted into the xml during the validation process. So if I call validate twice in a row, only handling the erros the second time around, the schema information is available.

```
serializedObject.Validate((x, y) => { });
serializedObject.Validate((x, y) => { // handle errors here because elements will have schema info available });
```

Obviously, this solution leaves much to be desired. What is the recommended way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Every time the ValidationEventHandler gets called, add the XmlSchemaValidationException.SourceObject Xmlelement to a list. Once validation is complete the schema information would be added to these objects, enabling me to access the information. i.e. Element.SchemaInfo.SchemaType.Name.

An XmlSchemaValidationException gets passed to the event handler with a property "SourceObject " which is an XmlElement.

```
            List<XmlElement> errorElements = new List<XmlElement>();

            serializedObject.Validate((x, y) =>
            {
                var exception = (y.Exception as XmlSchemaValidationException);

                if (exception != null)
                {
                    var element = (exception.SourceObject as XmlElement);

                    if (element != null)
                        errorElements.Add(new XmlValidationError(element));
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

[`XmlNode.SchemaInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.schemainfo.aspx) seems like it will provide this information.

I assume this will be populated when an `XmlDocument` is loaded using an `XmlReader` created to perform XSD validation.

However when performing validation the handler for validation errors ([`XmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationeventhandler.aspx)) there is only limited information available in the [`XmlSchemaException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaexception.aspx) instances passed with the [`ValidationEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.validationeventargs.aspx)). In particular there is no `XmlNode` or similar reference into the input document. There is however a reference to the [`SourceSchemaObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaexception.sourceschemaobject.aspx).

Comment: I'm using a XmlSerializer to serialise an object into xml. I would then like to validate that xml against a xsd. During the first call to validate there is absolutely no schema information available (all schema related porperties are null). On the second call. All the information is there.