# How to retrieve minoccurs value from XSD in C#?

Tags: c#, xsd

I am trying to figure out the correct cast type for the "Parent" property of an object of type XmlSchemaSimpleType. The below code is always returning "" as the "parent" variable is validated to null. Can anyone please help how to retrieve minOccurs from the parent of a simpleType ? Thank you!

```
private string GetMinOccurs(XmlSchemaSimpleType xsdSimpleType)
{
    var parent = xsdSimpleType.Parent as XmlSchemaElement;

    if (parent == null) return "";

    return parent.MinOccurs.ToString();
}
```

An example of my XSD is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="New_Type">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Amount" type="Amount_Type"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    <xsd:element name="Name" type="Name_Type"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="Amount_Type">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Amount</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:maxLength value="12" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comment of your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11570979/250725). the `Parent` property of an `XmlSchemaSimpleType` does not work like you think.  It looks like you are hoping it will return the `<element>` that has a type of the `XmlSchemaSimpleType` you are specifying.

But consider this situation:

```
<xsd:complexType name="New_Type">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Amount" type="Amount_Type"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    <xsd:element name="OtherAmount" type="Amount_Type"  minOccurs="10" maxOccurs="15" />
    <xsd:element name="Name" type="Name_Type"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="Amount_Type">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Amount</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:maxLength value="12" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Which would it return as there are 2 different elements with the same type?  As you can see from this example, a type can be used multiple times throughout an XSD and each occurance can have a different `MinOccurs` value.  If you want to get the `MinOccurs`, you need to find the exact `<element>` you want, even if the type is used just once.  But to do that you need to know where it is in the XSD.

This [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stan_kitsis/archive/2005/08/06/448572.aspx) is a few years old, but I think helps with the point.  You basically have to find the complex type using `XmlSchemaSet.GlobalTypes[]`, then you need to look through the `Particle` property.  In your case, there will be a single `XmlSchemaSequence` object in there (you'll probably need to cast).  Then you need to look through the items property to find your `Amount` element.  From there (after another cast), you can get MinOccurs.

If you don't know exactly what you are looking for, all of the collections in the `XmlSchemaObject` properties do have `GetEnumerator` methods, so you can use `foreach` to help scan everything.  None are generic though so you need to do a lot of casting, but this is basically what you have to do:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry item in set.GlobalTypes)
{
    // set.GlobalTypes.GetEnumerator returns an object, so you need to cast to DictionaryEntry 
    // DictionaryEntry.Key and DictionaryEntry.Value are objects too so you need to cast again
    // Particle is an XmlSchemaObject, so you need to cast to an XmlSchemaSequence

    var seq = (XmlSchemaSequence)((XmlSchemaComplexType)item.Value).Particle;

    // XmlSchemaSequence.Items also returns an XmlSchemaObject so you need to cast again to XmlSchemaElement.

    foreach (XmlSchemaElement i in seq.Items)
    {
        if (i.SchemaTypeName == new XmlQualifiedName("Amount_Type"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.MinOccursString);
        }
    }
}
```

But this is just an example to show how to get where you want to go.  You need to do some type checking before each of the casts in case it fails.  For example, `var seq = (XmlSchemaSequence)((XmlSchemaComplexType)item.Value).Particle;` will throw an exception after it gets to the second type in your XSD since it is not a complex type, it is a simple type.

A LINQ solution might be easier if you know exactly what you want:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("your XSD path");
var ns = XNamespace.Get(@"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

var minOccurs = from element in xDoc.Descendants()
                where (String)element.Attribute("type") == "Amount_Type"
                select (String)element.Attribute("minOccurs");
```

This method at least lets you scan the document quickly for any type that matches your `Amount_Type` and grabs the minOccurs (or returns null of there is no `minOccurs` attribute).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed clarification. I appreciate your help on this. Now I understand why it does not work the way I expected.

Comment: @Jyina just to add something, and this is too the comment made by leppie when you asked the question... the debugged is your friend here.  Read in the XSD into an `XmlSchemaSet`, pause the code with a break at some point after the `XmlSchemaSet` is compiled, then look at each of the properties.  I think as you explore them in the debugger, it will help you understand what things are.  That and the MSDN documentation on the [`XmlSchemaSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.aspx)

Comment: Thank you.That definitely helped me understand better.