# Accessing schema information during XML validation

Tags: c#, xml, validation, schema, linq-to-xml

I have some bad XML that fails validation against its schema. The errors are almost all the same -- empty elements which violate the document model, -- but they occur for potentially hundreds of different elements in the document.

My intended solution is to validate the document, capture the offending empty elements from the SourceObject property of the exception objects generated (if any) in an XElement list, then remove those elements from the document. However, the SourceObject property is always null.

After doing some reading about it, I've learned that the document object is not populated with schema information until after validation occurs. However, taking this into account, I still can't get any useful information from the validation process because the relevant object properties are always null, regardless of when I attempt to access them.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public void FixXml(string xmlDoc)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc);
    XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schema.Add("", @"../../test.xsd");
    schema.Compile();

    doc.Validate(schema, (Callback));

    foreach (XElement element in errors)
    {
        // This is where I'd start making changes to the document if the list didn't contain a bunch of nulls.
    }
}
```

Callback method:
*(I'll probably stuff this into a lambda when I'm confident the code is working).*

```
private void Callback(object sender, ValidationEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    XmlSchemaValidationException ex = (eventArgs.Exception as XmlSchemaValidationException);

    if (ex != null)
    {
        XElement element = (ex.SourceObject as XElement);
        errors.Add(element);
    }
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858926/capture-schema-information-when-validating-xdocument/8112949) and its answer have been useful to me, and I've applied some pieces of the solution to my own project, but it still doesn't seem to work. I feel like I'm missing something obvious and silly here.

Comment: I can't make the code from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8112949/3744182), work at all, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/3E0FJM.  It doesn't even compile since `serializedObject` is not defined.

Comment: OK, I have a 50% answer: to get the `XElement` you need to do `doc.CreateNavigator().CheckValidity(schema, callback);`, demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6hYaHH.  But `SourceSchemaObject` always seems to be `null`.

Comment: But maybe there's something wrong with the schema I picked.  Can you [edit] your question to include sample XML and XSD?

Comment: You are taking the wrong approach to null data.  The null data is required and need to be filled in.  You need to report the errors and get them fixed.  It is useless to process data where the data is required.  Suppose you have medical data and a Social Security number is required for a doctor to get reimbursed.  Processing the data without the SS is not going to get you anywhere.  The doctor need to go back to patient and get the number.  You need to list the missing data to help the doctor finish a database record.

Comment: @jdweng I completely agree, and your approach was the first thing we tried. However, when you're dealing with a provider who obviously didn't care enough to check their work against the standardized and publicly-available schema we both agreed to use, and you email them saying "hey, this breaks things on our end and here's exactly why and how to fix it," and they respond with "wow, neat, good luck with that," then Plan B is all you've got.

Comment: I would edit the schema and change the minimum numbers or the "is required" properties to allow for nulls.  You are getting "false failures" if the values are truly not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that [`XmlSchemaValidationException.SourceObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidationexception.sourceobject?#System_Xml_Schema_XmlSchemaValidationException_SourceObject) is `null` is explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidationexception.sourceobject?#System_Xml_Schema_XmlSchemaValidationException_SourceObject)

> When an `XmlSchemaValidationException` is thrown during validation of a class that implements the `IXPathNavigable` interface such as the `XPathNavigator` or `XmlNode` class, the object returned by the `SourceObject` property is an instance of a class that implements the `IXPathNavigable` interface.
>
> When an `XmlSchemaValidationException` is thrown during validation by a validating `XmlReader` object, the value of the `SourceObject` property is null.

Unfortunately, [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument) does not implement [`IXPathNavigable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.ixpathnavigable) and so `SourceObject` is, as documented, `null`.

If all you need is the `SourceObject`, you can create call [`Extensions.CreateNavigator(this XNode node)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.extensions.createnavigator?#System_Xml_XPath_Extensions_CreateNavigator_System_Xml_Linq_XNode_) to create a navigator for your document, then validate using [`XPathNavigator.CheckValidity(XmlSchemaSet, ValidationEventHandler)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.checkvalidity?#System_Xml_XPath_XPathNavigator_CheckValidity_System_Xml_Schema_XmlSchemaSet_System_Xml_Schema_ValidationEventHandler_) like so:

```
var errors = new List<XmlSchemaValidationException>();

ValidationEventHandler callback = (sender, args) =>
{
    var exception = (args.Exception as XmlSchemaValidationException);
    if (exception != null)
    {
        errors.Add(exception);
    }
};          

var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();
navigator.CheckValidity(schema, callback);          

foreach (var exception in errors)
{
    var node = (XObject)exception.SourceObject;

    // Do something with the node.
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", node.GetType(), node.ToString());
    Assert.IsTrue(node != null, "node != null");
}
```

However, experimentation shows that [`XmlSchemaException.SourceSchemaObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaexception.sourceschemaobject?#System_Xml_Schema_XmlSchemaException_SourceSchemaObject) always seems to be null with this approach, and also [`XElement.IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.system-xml-serialization-ixmlserializable-getschema?#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_System_Xml_Serialization_IXmlSerializable_GetSchema) is not populated.  I'm not sure why the source schema object is not passed in, but testing in .NET Core 3.0.0 shows it is not.  (Possibly this is related to [Issue  #38748: XSD Validation Errors- Missing details on xsd schema error code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38748) which was closed as not being currently implemented.)

If you need the source schema object as well, you will need to follow the approach from the [documentation for `Extensions.GetSchemaInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.extensions.getschemainfo?#System_Xml_Schema_Extensions_GetSchemaInfo_System_Xml_Linq_XElement_) and validate the `XDocument` using [`XDocument.Validate(XDocument, XmlSchemaSet, ValidationEventHandler, Boolean addSchemaInfo)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.extensions.validate?#System_Xml_Schema_Extensions_Validate_System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_System_Xml_Schema_XmlSchemaSet_System_Xml_Schema_ValidationEventHandler_System_Boolean_).  This populates the schema information into the LINQ to XML tree -- but, sadly, prevents `SourceObject` from being set.  Instead, when errors are detected, you will need to traverse the `XElement` hierarchy looking for elements and attributes for which [`GetSchemaInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.extensions.getschemainfo) returns an [`IXmlSchemaInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.ixmlschemainfo) for which [`Validity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.ixmlschemainfo.validity#System_Xml_Schema_IXmlSchemaInfo_Validity) is not [`Valid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidity#System_Xml_Schema_XmlSchemaValidity_Valid):

```
var errors = new List<XmlSchemaValidationException>();

ValidationEventHandler callback = (sender, args) =>
{
    var exception = (args.Exception as XmlSchemaValidationException);
    if (exception != null)
    {
        errors.Add(exception);
    }
};          

doc.Validate(schema, callback, true);           

foreach (var exception in errors)
{
    // Handle the exception itself.
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
}

if (errors.Count > 0)
{
    // If there were any errors, traverse the entire document looking for invalid nodes:
    DumpInvalidNodes(doc.Root);
}
```

Where the example method `DumpInvalidNodes` is modified from the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.extensions.getschemainfo?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Schema_Extensions_GetSchemaInfo_System_Xml_Linq_XElement_)

```
//Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.extensions.getschemainfo?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Schema_Extensions_GetSchemaInfo_System_Xml_Linq_XElement_
//with an added null check:
static void DumpInvalidNodes(XElement el)  
{  
    if (el.GetSchemaInfo().Validity != XmlSchemaValidity.Valid)  
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Element {0}",  
            el.AncestorsAndSelf()  
            .InDocumentOrder()  
            .Aggregate("", (s, i) => s + "/" + i.Name.ToString()));  
    foreach (XAttribute att in el.Attributes())  
    {
        var si = att.GetSchemaInfo();

        // MUST CHECK FOR NULL HERE
        // Because w3 standard attributes like xmlns:xsi will have null SchemaInfo
        // when not included in the schema, rather than being reported as Invalid.
        if (si != null && si.Validity != XmlSchemaValidity.Valid)  
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Attribute {0}",  
                att  
                .Parent  
                .AncestorsAndSelf()  
                .InDocumentOrder()  
                .Aggregate("",  
                    (s, i) => s + "/" + i.Name.ToString()) + "/@" + att.Name.ToString()  
                );  
    }
    foreach (XElement child in el.Elements())  
        DumpInvalidNodes(child);  
}
```

Note my testing showed that the documentation code needed to be modified to check for `XAttribute.GetSchemaInfo()` returning `null`.  This seems to happen for w3c-standard attributes like `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` when not explicitly included in the schema.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wriNnf).

*Update*: it seems `doc.CreateNavigator().CheckValidity(schema, callback)` does not work on earlier versions of the Full Framework; e.g. on .Net 4.7 an exception `System.NotSupportedException: This XPathNavigator does not support XSD validation` is thrown.  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R9uFlZ).  If you encounter this problem you will have to use the second approach.

Comment: The first solution did indeed throw a NotSupportedException, but the second solution provides me with schema information about invalid elements after validation, so I can likely adapt it to fit my needs. Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: @Trashface - there's an article here: http://geekswithblogs.net/.NETonMyMind/archive/2006/05/02/76957.aspx about accessing validation information during validation entirely through `XmlReader`, but honestly it looks extremely involved - probably not worth it unless you run into performance problems with approach #2 above, which essentially doubles the time required by adding an extra document traversal.